# How to get javascript control from JQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in JQuery,

How can I get the control as a javascript object from a JQuery object

```
var _object = $(this). ??
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most common
`var _object = $(this)[0];`

If you have more than 1 elements matched: `$(this)[0]`, `$(this)[1]`, `$(this)[2]` and so on.

`$(this).get()` is also possible. It's only advantage over the array model is that it allows selection of the kind `$(this).get(-1)` where it gets you the last matched object

Answer (score 0):

```
var _object = $(this)[0];
```

I think this is right, can't check though because I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, simply use `this`.

`$(this)[0] == this` if `this` is a DOM element. If it's something else, e.g. a selector, `$(this)[0]` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (e) {
    var a = false;
    try {
        $(this)[0];
        a = true;
    } catch (h) {}
    alert(a.toString());
})(window);
```

Comment: You have accidentally created [two](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2098956/unver-kizilay) [accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2098970/unver-kizilay). For how to merge them, see [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge).