# How can I convert a jQuery object to a JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my old code:

```
checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
```

As you know, `checkboxes` will be an array. Now I need to limit selecting scope. So this is my new code:

```
checkboxes = $('.myclass input[name=foo]');
```

But in this case `checkboxes` isn't an array anymore, it's a jQuery object. How can I make it the same as `getElementsByName('foo')`'s result?

---

Note that `$('.myclass input[name=foo]')[0]` won't work either.

Comment: Make sure all your `checkboxes` are inside an container whose class is `myclass`. Otherwise `$('.myclass input[name=foo]')[0]` will definitely work.

Comment: @RohanKumar Actually I've some other checkboxes which are out of the `.myclass` element and I don't want to select them. That's why I'm trying to use `$('.myclass input[name=foo]')` instead of `document.getElementsByName('foo')`. Anyway, my question is a totally different thing.

Comment: is `.myclass` also an input?

Comment: Can you show up your relevant code with html to solve your problem. You can create a Snippet for this too. Also, check that you have included a jquery version in your page.

Comment: @RohanKumar Thanks for your attention, but my problem has been resolved. Satpal's answer is the one I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, but @Charlie's answer is short and sweet.

Comment: Its SO, so every developer will definitely learn from this site. And you have many ways to do a single job in an optimised and even in a shortest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)

```
checkboxes = $('.myclass input[name=foo]').toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` and create an array of underlying DOM which `getElementsByName()` returns

```
checkboxes  = $('.myclass input[name=foo]').map(function(){ return this;}).get();
```

I would recommend @Charlie [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43315221)

---

You don't need to convert to Node elements array. Change your function to

```
function toggle(source, target) {
    $(target).find('input[name=foo]').prop('checked', source.checked);
}
```

*Usage*

```
toggle(source, '.compare_people')
toggle(source, '.compare_posts')
```

Comment: It's nice of you recommending the answer of a person who has much less rep than you.

Comment: @Shafizadeh, Reputation at SO means nothing. Clearly he gave a better answer I totally forgot about that function

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var checked = [];
$.each($("input[name='foo']:checked"), function(){
checked.push($(this). val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Charlie already pointed out that jQuery objects have a `toArray()` function. That would work I think. Figured it was also worth noting that there is also a `.makeArray()` function for generally converting array-like objects to native JavaScript arrays. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=foo]")

Answer (score 0):

Getting javascript object from jquery object by `$('selector')[0]` should work. See the answer from this link [How to get javascript control from JQuery object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388306/how-to-get-javascript-control-from-jquery-object)
I suspect your selector is the reason why the above approach doesn't work. Add double quotes to name value will make it work:

```
checkboxes = $('.myclass input[name="foo"]');
```